# Is there a ComboBox that has Items like a TcxRadioGroup?

Tags: delphi, combobox, devexpress, delphi-2007, items

The TcxRadioGroup component of DevExpress has a very nice way to specify items. You can specify a Caption and a Value (and a Tag) for each TcxRadioGroupItem.

The TcxComboBox and the normal TComboBox of Delphi on the other hand use TStrings to store its items.

While TStrings can have a Name and an Object, there is no easy way to hook up a name and a value using the form designer of the Delphi IDE.

Is there a ComboBox control (preferably from DevExpress) that allows to visually design its items with a Caption and a Value?

PS: I'm *not* looking for a DB aware control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a TcxImageComboBox. See [here](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A847.aspx) - you don't have to assign images despite the name. You can also edit the items visually.

(I use it as cell editor in cxGrids because of the separation Description/Value.)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, nice :).

Comment: I doesn't sort though, but I solved that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185796/how-to-sort-the-items-of-a-tcximagecombobox-by-description

Answer (score 1):

[Raize Components](http://www.raize.com/DevTools/RzComps/Default.asp) have *TRzComboBox* which introduces a *Values* property as an addition to the existing *Items*.

Answer (score 1):

[ESBPCS for VCL](http://www.esbconsult.com/esbpcs/) has an enhanced Lookup ComboBox. It stores 2 Lists, the ones normally in TCombobox's Items as well as the new Values list. These two StringLists are in a 1-1 relationship. Use AsItem to retrieve the string currently displayed and AsValue to retrieve the "related" string from Values.

Answer (score 0):

Use a standard Delphi TComboBox, it can store a string (for visualization, and an object of any TObject descendant that you implement yourself, i.e you can store anything associated to a string in the dropdown).

Comment: Yes, you can store data in TStrings, but there is no visual editor that you can use to setup something. I asked for "visually design" if you read the question again.